# Script needs to be stopped after 24 hours

Tags: bash, scripts

I would like to run my script for **24 hrs**, then it needs to be stopped
even if processes are still going on.

Answer (score 20):

Use `timeout`:

```
timeout 24h my_script
```

Or use `at` to kill at a specific time, something like this:

```bash
my_script &
my_script_pid=$!

at 13:37 <<< "kill $my_script_pid"
# or
at now+24hours <<< "kill $my_script_pid"

# optional, if you want to close the terminal:
disown
```

Using `at` can have some benefits, e.g. when launching your script via `ssh` and detach from the current terminal (-> `disown`), you can close the connection / the terminal.
But you should be aware, that if the script stops before the time is up, the PID might get reused. You might be able to find the PID with other means, e.g. `ps aux` or `pkill myscript.sh` or so.

You could also use `screen` or `nohup` with the first command.

Comment: Note that pids are eventually reused, so `at` being appropriate depends on the context in which it's running: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414974/5471

Comment: There are no specific benefits to `at` when launching processes over ssh (or if you close the terminal), since the script would be terminated when the session is closed unless you start it with something like `nohup my_script`, but then you might just as well use `nohup timeout 86400 my_script` instead.

Comment: thanks fpr your comments, added the information.

Comment: For extra readability, consider replacing `86400` with `24h`.

Answer (score 4):

A few alternatives based on the fact that `kill 0` signals all processes in the current process group.

For example:

```
sh -c './script & sleep 24h; kill 0'
```

Or:

```
./script | ( sleep 24h; kill 0 )
```

Or:

```
./script | { sleep 24h; kill 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use crontab to kill the service

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <(crontab -l) <(echo "0 0 0 0 0 kill-scripty.sh") | crontab -

# do something
```